# Map latitude and longitude to state in SAS

Tags: sas, latitude-longitude, shapefile

I have about 100,000 latitude and longitude pairs (to 4 decimals) and I would like to assign each pair to a US state.  Does anyone know how to do this in SAS?  Is it possible to import shapefiles into SAS for this task?

Comment: SAS has preloaded shapefiles, but you'd have to project your lat/long onto SAS's particular projection.  How comfortable are you with map projections and manipulating things like that?

Comment: I have never used map projections in SAS. I'm pretty experienced with SAS Base procedures but not with the preloaded shapefiles.

Comment: Hmm.  I would look up that then - "projections SAS gmap gproject" - and see if it makes sense to you.  I don't think I know it well enough to give you an actual answer, but I think that's the direction you need to go.

Comment: PROC GINSIDE, see the documentation for a direct example with States and counties for a series of points. https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grmapref/69722/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0qjcc8hugcjb2n1x3bmuaar16f0.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: the following answer assumes you have a license for SAS Graph and the Maps library is properly set up on your installation. This will not work on SAS University Edition. If you need to download the MAPS files they are here: http://support.sas.com/rnd/datavisualization/mapsonline/index.html

You don't need to import the SHP file for the US, SAS already has these built in. You can use PROC GINSIDE to determine what state and/or county the points are located.

An example is located here:
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grmapref/69722/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0qjcc8hugcjb2n1x3bmuaar16f0.htm

And copied here, for SO rules.

```
goptions reset=global border;
data gpscounties;
  input longitude latitude site $;
  x=longitude*arcos(-1)/180;
  x=x*(-1);
  y=latitude*arcos(-1)/180;
datalines;
-77.0348 40.0454 a
-78.4437 39.1623 b
-78.4115 39.3751 c
-78.7646 40.6354 d
;
run;
proc ginside data=gpscounties map=mapssas.counties out=gpscounties;
  id state county;
run;
proc sort data=gpscounties;
  by site;
run;

proc print data=gpscounties;
  var site state county x y;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you Reeza.  This is tremendous and exactly what I needed.  I did not know about GINSIDE.  Thank you!